# Theming Views, getting a list of object I have access of

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm Currently trying to theme a view.
Unfortunately I'm having a hard time to find elements I should use to access my fields.

Is there any where on the web, where I could find those variables ? or the parent one, that will allow me to find out other by searching down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3 tools that I find vital to this is:

1. Click "Theme: Information" in the view page itself. This will give you a list of template files being used for the view and suggestions of template files you can use to override them by placing them in your theme folder (or a template subfolder of your theme depending on how you have set up in your .info file).
2. [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) - this will allow you to inspect just about any aspect of your site and all the variables, fields etc available to you in a particular node/view.
3. [Drupalforfirebug module](http://drupal.org/project/drupalforfirebug) and accompanying firefox/chrome plugin. Although I find it somewhat buggy in certain areas of drupal, it is great for inspecting all aspects of drupal (especially views).

Comment: Thank you, I did not know there were tpl(s) files in the theme folder of views ! + upvote for going further in the issue with 2 more answer !